# Why did my comment get deleted?

Tags: discussion, comment, moderation

My reply to this [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235808/machine-learning-with-small-set-of-positive-outcomes/235810#comment447736_235810) got deleted. Why?

The OP commented:

> So to summarize the link: there results on which method is better are inconclusive, and it is easier to use the under/over-sampling. Right? – LazyCat 20 hours ago

to which I simply replied that he was correct.

Comment: it's probably [support], not [discussion].

Comment: [support] is more for help on understanding features of the site; I think discussion is more appropriate here. (but could be both).

Comment: It was flagged; while I don't agree with the specified reason, it might have been legitimately flagged as obsolete if the user you replied to had been on since you posted it, so I'd still have had a look at whether it could be deleted. While personally I try to leave sensible comments alone for at least a day or sometimes two (some flaggers are very proactive), I do mostly tend to act on comment flags after that sort of time, or if I am otherwise happy it served its purpose (which action would usually be to delete the comment). ...ctd

Comment: ctd... So if it had been me looking at it, and I was satisfied the person to who it was addressed had had seen it (or had very likely seen it), I might well have deleted it.

Comment: @Glen_b I think other readers might find the comment useful as well.

Comment: @Franck no doubt, but if that's the case you can always edit your answer to include that information (by rephrasing the question you responded to as a statement affirming the thing it was asking). Comments are not guaranteed to remain, but stuff in an answer is unlikely to be deleted. That's the way to make sure later readers get the benefit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [help page on comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):

> **When *shouldn't* I comment?**
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following: ...
>
> - Compliments which do not add new information ("+1, great answer!"); instead, up-vote it and pay it forward; ...

Your comment did *not* say "he was correct."  The record shows it said (in full)

> @LazyCat right.

That is ambiguous.  I interpreted it as not adding new information.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not a native speaker. Why is "right" ambiguous?

Comment: Because it most frequently is used as a casual acknowledgment that a post or statement has been received, without necessarily indicating anything else.

Comment: Even if the comment to which I replied to ended with "Right?"?

Comment: I don't see that in the quotation you have posted.  I *do* see it now in the thread itself.  The comment to which you responded actually said "So to summarize the link: there results on which method is better are inconclusive, and it is easier to use the under/over-sampling. Right?"  Your "right" *does* respond to that.  I apologize for the confusion.  (I was processing a flag and did not see the entire context of the exchange.)  I have restored your comment.

Comment: Looks like I had copy pasted the wrong comment :) I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks no worries.

Comment: Thank you.  We don't worry too much about comments--we all know they could disappear at any time--but I am alerted to be a little more cautious in processing flags in the future.